# bash script to open chrome then turn computer off when chrome is closed

Tags: linux, bash, wait

I would like to write the a startup script in bash to make an ubuntu box more grandpa-friendly.

The script should:

open chrome
wait until chrome is closed
turn computer off

so far I have

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    address="http:\\www.google.co.uk"
else
    address=$1
fi

echo starting the internet
google-chrome $address

while [ 1=1 ];
do
   grep_resp=$(ps aux | grep chrome)
   if [ -z "$grep_resp" ]; then
       echo turning computer off 
   else
       echo chrome still running
   fi
   sleep 5
done
```

but the grep for "chrome" is in the process list

Any aid?

Comment: +1 for "starting the internet" YMMD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that error because `$grep_resp` in this...

```
if [ -z $grep_resp ]; then
```

...probably expands into a string containing whitespace.  If you put quotes around it:

```
  if [ -z "$grep_resp" ]; then
```

It will do what you expect.  However, I think all of that may be unnecessary.  Chrome doesn't automatically background or anything when it runs, so you should be able to do this:

```
google-chrome $address
echo turning computer off
...
```

Comment: "turning computer off" happens as soon as finished loading"

Comment: That's odd, because with my version of Chrome (19) that's not the case.  You'll note that @bitmask's solution assumes the same behavior that mine does.

Comment: thanks, you are correct. I must have made a mistake somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=gramps

sudo -u "$user" -- chrome "$1"; shutdown -P now
```

where the script is run as root.

Answer (score 1):

Line 14 should be

```
if [ -z "$grep_resp" ]; then
```

It needs to be in quote because the string has spaces in it.